# Query array similarly to SQL query - PHP

Tags: php, arrays, sql-server

I am trying to write a quick script that only queries an MSSQL table once and then organizes the response on my end so that I don't have to keep querying mysql for the data.

hard to explain but what I've come up with is to grab everything i need in one query, and then organize each row into an array, then put that array into another all-inclusive array that I can then pull data from.

what I've got so far:

```
$allInclusiveArray = [];
$sumRecords = mssql_num_rows($result);
for ($i = 0; $i < $sumRecords; ++$i) {
    //get key values for array
    echo $value1= mssql_result($result, $i, 'key1');
    echo $value2= mssql_result($result, $i, 'key2');
    echo $value3= mssql_result($result, $i, 'key3');
    echo $value4= mssql_result($result, $i, 'key4');

    $tempArray = [
        "key1" => $value1,
        "key2" => $value2,
        "key3" => $value3,
        "key4" => $value4
    ];

    array_push($allInclusiveArray, $tempArray);
}
```

the end result would be an array that looks something like:

```
$allInclusiveArray = [
     [array with keys and values],
     [array with keys and values],
     [array with keys and values]
];
```

What I'm wondering is if there is a way to query this array to grab all values relating to one key, where another key has a fixed value. In mssql it would look something like `SELECT key1 FROM table WHERE key2 = value2`

One possibility could be to do a for loop and then run and if statement checking if both keys and values match up, for example:

```
for (i in length of array) {
    if (the array located at i has key2 equaling value2) {
        select the value of key1 from the array at this index
    }
}
```

---

EDIT: I ended up doing most of the sorting on MSSQL's side. I had a working PHP script on my side that sorted the bulk data, but even dealing with 20,000 records was taking forever.

Comment: You may try LINQ library for php at https://github.com/Athari/YaLinqo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this?

Here's an example: https://3v4l.org/MrqvI

```
function arrayQuery($array, $key, $match){
    foreach($array as $row){
        if(array_key_exists($key, $row) && $row[$key] == $match) return $row;
    }
    return $false;
}
```

This could easily be extended into a full class if you need more functionality

Answer (score 1):

[Here](http://mihai-stancu.ro/2015/09/14/multikeymaps-for-tuples/) is a blog post (/ rant) I wrote yesterday on the subject.

The bottom line is that `Doctrine` has query-able `ArrayCollections` with `SQL` like semantics (`Criteria` similar to an ORM query builder).

Resources for this are [here](https://github.com/doctrine/collections). If you use composer you can require the library in your project to use it directly.

It is used typically in conjunction with the ORM or ODM to filter through (partially load) large relationships (which is what [this article](http://mnapoli.fr/collection-interface-and-database-abstraction/) presents).